# Crear Formularios en Android y como tratarlos

Tags: android

Estoy diseñando una aplicación en Android y necesito crear un formulario con bastantes campos, mi idea es hacer un formulario con distintos apartados y en vez de hacer todos los apartados en una misma activity con un scroll vertical quiero crear una o varias activities que mediante botones de atrás y adelante pasando por los apartados... Aquí es cuando me surgen varias dudas:

¿Me merece la pena hacer todo en una misma activity y cambiar los campos que voy mostrando y habilitando los campos que necesite o distintas activities...?

También me gustaría añadir que cuando pasase hacia adelante y hacia atrás los campos que ya haya rellenado previamente que se me auto-rellenasen estos, aquí me surge otra duda:

¿Me merece la pena crearme algo como una clase "Formulario" que tenga atributos para cada uno de los distintos campos y que me vaya pasando entre activities o como sea que lo organice ese objeto y a la hora de abrir la activity obtenga del objeto los atributos de los campos?

Comment: Te sugeriria que lo hicieras en varias actividades para evitar tener que bajar. Aparte de eso es que el usuario comunmente no va a llenar un formulario que se ve muy largo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo más sencillo, sería crear varias actividades, no me gusta esta idea; lo que yo haría es precisamente lo que comentas, una clase Formulario que contenga todos los apartados y  crear otras clases que extiendan de esta clase padre de la cual hereden ciertos apartados.

o  puedes ir haciendo visibles los apartados según avances en tu aplicación:

```
vistaApartadoB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Mientras el apartado que no necesites lo puedes hacer invisible y colapsar la vista:

```
vistaApartadoA.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

y todos los apartados pueden estar en el mismo Layout.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que comentas parece que podria servirte hacer un *wizard*.

Puedes ahorrarte algo de trabajo y usar [Android Json Wizard](https://github.com/vijayrawatsan/android-json-form-wizard)

Solo necesitas agregar la dependencia a tu pom (Si trabajas con maven)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.vijayrawatsan</groupId>
    <artifactId>android-json-form-wizard</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

El truco consisten en generar un json con tus datos que necesitas cargar e irlos agrupando por "pasos"

```
{
    "count":"2",
    "paso1":{
        "fields":[
            {
                "key":"nombre",
                "type":"edit_text",
                "hint":"Enter Your Name",
                "value":"Vijay"
            }
        ],
        "title":"Paso 1 de N",
        "next":"paso2"
    },
    "paso2":{
        "fields":[
            {
                "key":"name",
                "type":"edit_text",
                "hint":"Algun dato",
                "value":"Dafult"
            }
        "title":"Paso 2",

    }
}
```